# iPython magic %logstart option -o not working

Tags: python, logging, ipython

I'm trying to save to file my iPython's session commands and output logging to file.
It seems like this should do it:

```
%logstart -o -r -t mylog.txt
```

When I run this:

```
print 3+2
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

I'd expect the log file to look like:

```
print 3+2
5
for i in range(5):
    print i

0
1
2
3
4
```

But all I get is:

```
%logstart -o -r -t mylog.txt
print 3+2
for i in range(10):
    print i
%logstop
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The log does not record print statements, only the value of entered expressions.  Thus, instead of printing, try having a statement return what you need.  Notice below how the result of 2+3 is displayed, while the result of print(2+3) is not:

```
# IPython log file
2+3
#[Out]# 5
print(2+3)
get_ipython().magic('logstop')
```